# String concatenation. What was I doing wrong and how does it work exactly? (Beginner)

Tags: javascript, string, loops, concatenation

So in the code below everything worked fine, until I got down to my first if statement. I kept getting the wrong results in test because I had (crazyString = char + crazyString) instead of what I have below. I now understand I could have used +=, but i was just wondering how come addition order is so strict in javascript.

```
const crazyCaps = (origString) => {
   let crazyString = '';
   for (let i = 0; i < origString.length; i++) {
      let char = origString[i];
      if (i % 2 === 1) { 
         char = char.toUpperCase();
         crazyString = crazyString + char;
      } else {
         crazyString = crazyString + origString[i];
      }    
   }
   return crazyString;
};
```

Comment: Because `crazyString = char + crazyString` will *prepend* the char, not *append* it

Comment: 'but i was just wondering how come addition order is so strict in javascript' - because `+` on strings denotes concatenation, not addition.

Comment: Also note that expressions in JS may have side effects on data referenced in subexpressions, so even if an operator in JS implements a commutative mathematical function, it would be a bad idea to let commutativity carry over from the mathematical domain. Example (admittedly, a contrived one): `let a=1; a + (() => { a += 4; return a; })();` vs. `let a=1; (() => { a += 4; return a; })() + a;`.

Answer (score 0):

'+' with strings is concatenation and not addition

Example:

- 'A' + 'B' becomes AB
- 'B' + 'A' becomes BA // not AB !!

```js
const crazyCaps = (origString) => {
  let crazyString = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < origString.length; i++) {
    let char = origString[i];
    if (i % 2 === 1) {
      char = char.toUpperCase();
      crazyString = char + crazyString;
      // You are pre-pending Capital Letter to output String
    } else {
      crazyString = crazyString + origString[i];
    }
    // Iterations for an input of krishna: 
    // <Char> <crazyString>
    // k
    // Rk
    // Rki
    // SRki
    // SRkih
    // NSRkih
    // NSRkiha
  }
  return crazyString;
};

console.log(crazyCaps("krishna"));
```